# Anchor mouse pointer doesn´t work with CSS and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the cursor pointer in an anchor to "not-allowed" when it has  a "disabled" class.
I have tried the following, with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Link to test: https://plnkr.co/edit/isoqoP2EbKjWb9fkfQpN?p=preview

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked lefttabs well">
      <li><a>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="disabled">Perfil</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Styles go here */
.nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a { cursor: pointer; }

.disabled {
    color: #900;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you're **CSS** code to:

```
.nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a { cursor: pointer; }

.disabled {
    color: #900;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You have to remove the `pointer-events: none;` this stops the cursor from changing (Or removes it all together) and therefore remains the same, despite you setting the cursor.

Comment: @LuizAlves Anytime.